# How to view postgres on the hsql database manager

Tags: database, postgresql, hsqldb

Mmm. I put the postgre jar on the lib folder of hsql database manager but then I tried to use the database manager an error occurs "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.postgresql.Driver".

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to put the jar in the lib folder. You need to include the jar in the command line that you use to execute DatabaseManager. An example for Windows below:

```
java -cp /path/to/hsqldb.jar;/path/to/postgres/pg.jdbc3.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing
```